# How to place target levels just below/above the generated Buy/Sell signal on pinescript

Tags: pine-script, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

[image: This image tells exactly what i wanna code]

```
if (buysellsetup == 2)
    if SellTarget1Achieved == true and (TradeEntered == true)
        label.delete(sellTP1)
        label.delete(buyTP1)
        sellTP1 :=  label.new(bar_index, STP1, " TP-1 : "+ tostring(STP1,format.mintick) + " (" + tostring((Current_Trade_Entry_Point-STP1)/STP1*100,"#.##")+ "%)" + " (HIT✔️)", style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.black)
        
    else 
        label.delete(sellTP1)
        label.delete(buyTP1)
        sellTP1 :=  label.new(bar_index, STP1, " TP-1 : "+ tostring(STP1,format.mintick)+ " (" + tostring((Current_Trade_Entry_Point-STP1)/STP1*100,"#.##")+ "%)", style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.black)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are (constantly) deleting and creating new levels with `bar_index` as x location. That's why the labels are always on the last bar.

You should add another condition to your if checks to prevent this until your targets are hit or whenever you want to delete them.

Comment: could you plz give some idea on code? what should i add.. plz